# twig extension name global

Tags: global, twig-extension

Before version 1.12 in twig extensions it was possibile to define a getGlobals method like this:

```
public function getGlobals()
{
    return array($this->getName() => $this);
}
```

to set a global name for extensions that implement many methods and it was possibile to call a "foo" estension with bar and baz methods like this:

```
{{ foo.bar }} {{ foo.baz }}
```

Considering that getGlobasl method is now deprecated and will be removed in Twig 2, how could it be possibile to obtain the same effect without using getGlobals?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself just now. You can 'fix' this using an EventListener, hook into kernel.view:

Obviously only works when using the `@Template` annotation from the sensio extra bundle.

```
public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
{
    $params = $event->getControllerResult();
    $params['baddesign'] = $this->myservice->getSomethingThatsUsedEverywhere();
    $event->setControllerResult($params);
}
```

---

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        KernelEvents::VIEW => 'onKernelView',
    );
}
```

---

```
mybundle.globalvarlistener:
    class: MyBundle\EventListener\MyListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```